# Firebase Login using nodejs does not persist

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an application where I login using the server side. The client side makes API requests to the server for authenticated resources. I've realized that the user does not stay logged in for long on the server. In fact, once they log in after 3 minutes, they are logged out. What should I do?

Here's the code I use to log them in on the server side

```
return app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

User fills out login form on the client -> We make a call on the server that executes the code above -> User can access restricted resource